# replace onclick action to display inline output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, class, if-statement

i want to change the behavior of the button in this function

```
$STRING .= '<a href="'.$GLOBALS['CORE_THEME']['links']['author'].'/author/'.$author_info->user_login. '" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">'.$CORE->_e(array('auction','41')).'</a>';
```

to when clicked to display the output of this function

```
 $data = get_user_meta( $authorID, 'cellno', true);
        if(strlen($data) > 0){ 
        echo "<span><i class='fa fa-phone'></i> <a href='phone:".$data."' rel='nofollow' target='_blank'</a> </span>";
```

so that when " class="btn btn-info btn-lg" is clicked it will display the phone number inside it, for now it shows contact author, and opens a new page to the author page.

thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php 
$STRING .= '<a href="#" onclick="javascript:showPhoneNumber();" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">'.$CORE->_e(array('auction','41')).'</a>';
$data = get_user_meta( $authorID, 'cellno', true);
if(strlen($data) > 0){
    echo "<span id='phoneNumber'><i class='fa fa-phone'></i> <a href='phone:".$data."' rel='nofollow' target='_blank'</a> </span>";
    }
?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#phoneNumber').hide();
    });

    function showPhoneNumber(){
        $('#phoneNumber').show();
    }
</script>
```

Also, try learning onclick events.

Comment: sorry but where should i place the <script>, cause placing it after the <?php...?> does nothing

Comment: Add the script in the page where you display the contents of `<?php..?>`. Also include jquery library prior to the `<script>` contents. If you are a beginner, check tutorials on creating web pages with jquery and php.